# Compilation error <identifier> expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So it's probably something simple, but I still can't work it out by myself. 
What does this mean?

```
GET.java:27: error: <identifier> expected
        out.println("</p></body></html>");
                   ^
GET.java:27: error: illegal start of type
        out.println("</p></body></html>");
```

This is the code for my java servlet:

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import javax.servlet.*;
  import javax.servlet.http.*;

  public class GET extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                      throws ServletException, IOException {
      res.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/prdocutorders.txt");
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
      out.println("<html><body><p>");
      pw.println("<h3>Congratulations! Your order information:</h3>");
      Enumeration e = req.getParameterNames();
      while ( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
        String name = (String)e.nextElement();
        String vals[] = (String[])req.getParameterValues(name);
        if ( vals != null )
          for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
            out.println(name + ": " + vals[i] + "<br>");
      }
       if ( vals != null )
          for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
            pw.println(name + ": " + vals[i] + "<br>");
      }
        out.println("</p></body></html>");
     // out.close();
    }
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Indent your code. Use curly braces in a systematic way.

Answer (score 2):

Balancing braces is **mandatory**. You have a lost braces before the statement `out.println("</p></body></html>");`

As a side note it's easier to catch mistake like that by

- always using braces
- correctly indenting your code

---

Edit: some parts of your code seems incorrect, you probably want this:

```
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = (String) e.nextElement();
    String vals[] = (String[]) req.getParameterValues(name);
    if (vals != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            out.println(name + ": " + vals[i] + "<br>");
            pw.println(name + ": " + vals[i] + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
out.println("</p></body></html>");
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it doesn't like vals now tho.. "cannot find symbol" even though I declare it

Comment: You're declaring it in another block. Each block has its own scope.

Comment: The second `if ( vals != null )` block seems unwanted or misplaced

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
if ( vals != null) { //has no opening bracket
```

You need to add { to your code.  Or you need to remove } right before

```
out.println("</p></body></html>");
```